# Why is the program asking me several times for an input before executing?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x

I have been doing an exercise for me to get more comfortable with the basics but this program won't run as I want or expect it to run. 
I have already written similar codes using input and so on but this happened to me the first time, so I wonder why this code is not working as expected.

I expect the program to ask me `"Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline."` 21 times and depending on typing `1 or 0`, it adds one to the variable agreements or declines and of course, showing me the current score after inserting an input like:

```
Who wants to play volleyball on sunday from 4pm to 6pm?
If more 12 or more people agree, I will book a field for us.
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
1 YES vs. 0 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
1 YES vs. 1 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.

# and so on...
```

But instead it gives me:

```
Who wants to play volleyball on sunday from 4pm to 6pm?
If more 12 or more people agree, I will book a field for us.
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
11
1 YES vs. 0 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
00
1 YES vs. 1 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
00
1 YES vs. 2 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
00
1 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
2 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
3 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
4 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
5 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
6 YES vs. 3 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
10
6 YES vs. 4 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
01
7 YES vs. 4 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
00
7 YES vs. 5 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
8 YES vs. 5 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
9 YES vs. 5 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
10 YES vs. 5 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
10
10 YES vs. 6 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
10
10 YES vs. 7 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
00
10 YES vs. 8 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
0
01
11 YES vs. 8 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
12 YES vs. 8 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
11
13 YES vs. 8 NO
Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.
1
Cool,I am gonna book a field for us.SEE YOU ON SUNDAY at 4pm.LET'S GOOOOO!!!
Have a nice week until then !
```

If you wonder why there is `11, 00, 01 or 10` sometimes: 
The second number is what I had to insert as an input again and the first number got printed by the program.

And if there is only one number, `1 or 0`:
This is my input.

And as you may already have noticed:
It doesn't matter what I insert first or second as an input. Only the last input matters and counts for some reason, I don't know.

(I haven't figured out how to visualize(like: italic, bold or colors) your code yet, that is why I had to explain the code here a little bit...)

My code:

```
print("Who wants to play volleyball on sunday from 4pm to 6pm?")
print("If more 12 or more people agree, I will book a field for us.")
print("Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.")

answer = input()
z = int(input(answer))
agreements = 0
declines = 0

for i in range(0, 21):
    try:
        z = int(input(answer))
        if z == 1:
            agreements += 1
            print(agreements, "YES vs.", declines, "NO")
            print("Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.")

            answer = input()
        elif z == 0:
            declines += 1
            print(agreements, "YES vs.", declines, "NO")
            print("Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.")

            answer = input()
        else:
            raise
    except:
        print("Please type '1' or '0'.Try again.")

if agreements >= 12:
    print("Cool,I am gonna book a field for us."
          "SEE YOU ON SUNDAY at 4pm."
          "LET'S GOOOOO!!!")
else:
    print("Unfortunately we didn't manage to get enough people for booking a field."
          "Maybe next time! :)")

print("Have a nice week until then !")
```

No matter how I look at it, I just can't find the issue here.
It is gonna be such a stupid mistake...

My apologies and thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you should do `z = int(input())` or `z = int(answer)` instead of `z = int(input(answer))` ?

Comment: Oh yeah actually using `z = int(answer)` solves my problem. It was my bad that I kinda doubled it, using input and answer. Thank you. BUT now another problem occurs. It seems like my try and except is not working now because whenever I write something different than 0 or 1, the program ends with 

`Please type '1' or '0'.Try again.`(times the loop range)
`Unfortunately we didn't mangage to get enough people for booking a field.Maybe next time! :)
Have a nice week until then !`

without asking me to insert an input again which it usually should,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for far more `input()` then you should. Each `input()` in your code will print what is in its parenthesis (if anything) and wait for an input by the user: you.

Thats why there are more inputs then you think there are - and lots of outputs you do not think should happen. Essentially you are prompting yourself for some text that is then used as message and printed as prompt for the next input() in your code...

This:

```
answer = input()  # input-prompt. no output. will store inputted thing in answer
z = int(input(answer))  # input-prompt. Will print content of 'answer' as message
                        # and wait for another input of you
agreements = 0
declines = 0

# etc..... same for your inner loops.
```

Next problem: your for-loop will increase even if an invalid input is given so you dont get asked 21 "valid" times if you mis-inputs 21 times.

You can simplyfy this by not using "numbers" to compare and use a function to ask as long as invalid inputs are given:

```
def agreeToPlay():
    """Loop until either 0 or 1 is inputted - remove whitespsaces for convenience.
    Returns True on agreement, else False"""

    # loop with no end
    while True:
        choice = input("Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline:").strip()

        # only way out of the while is by inputing either 0 or 1:
        if choice in ["1","0"]:
            # only way to break out of the endless loop is valid input
            return choice == "1"  # return True if 1 else False
```

You use this function in your main program:

```
print("Who wants to play volleyball on sunday from 4pm to 6pm?")
print("If more 12 or more people agree, I will book a field for us.")
print("Type '1' if you agree - Type '0' if you decline.")

agreements = 0
declines = 0
answers = []

# shortcut:
# while agreements + declines < 21 and agreements < 12  # ends as soon as 12 agreed

while agreements + declines < 21: 
    if agreeToPlay(): # ask until valid, then increment the correct one based
                      # on return of True / False
        agreements += 1
    else:
        declines +=1 

    print(agreements, "YES vs.", declines, "NO")

if agreements >= 12:
    print("Cool,I am gonna book a field for us."
          "SEE YOU ON SUNDAY at 4pm."
          "LET'S GOOOOO!!!")
else:
    print("Unfortunately we didn't manage to get enough people for booking a field."
          "Maybe next time! :)")
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. What was I thinking when I wrote this part of code...mhh. 
Oh wow this is interesting. It is completely different compared to my atempt. Thank you for the insights and your time helping me. I appreciate it. 
**Thank you mister Artner !**